# Begin, Rescue with API endpoint

Tags: ruby, rescue

Here is my method:

```
def get_video_duration
  @time ||= Panda.get("/videos/#{@video.panda_id}/metadata.json")["duration"]
  format_duration
end
```

I need to write this method "better" in wrapping it with a `begin`, `rescue` block so that `@time` could be nil depending on the response from the API.

Comment: Do you want to execute `Panda.get` always, or only when `@time` is nil/false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, possible using *inline* `rescue` clause.

```
def get_video_duration
    @time ||= Panda.get("/videos/#{@video.panda_id}/metadata.json")["duration"] rescue nil
    format_duration
end
```

Or better explicitly do it.

```
def get_video_duration
  @time ||= Panda.get("/videos/#{@video.panda_id}/metadata.json")["duration"]
rescue YourException
  @time = nil
  format_duration
end
```

Comment: You ruin the logic of the OP. In the original question there was lazy instantiation of `@time` while you set it in any case despite whether is was already set or not.

Comment: @mudasobwa If that's what OP meant, I will delete this. Lets wait OP to come back and respond, this is not what (s)he wanted.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - Thanks for the help! The lazy instantiation of `@time` is what I was going for

Comment: @dennismonsewicz Is this solved your problem...? Now

Answer (score 1):

Maybe break it down with an additional method :

```
def fetch_video_duration

  Panda.get("/videos/#{@video.panda_id}/metadata.json")["duration"]

  rescue
    return nil
end

def get_video_duration
  @time ||= fetch_video_duration

  format_duration
end
```